# Check if view element is added to layout or not programmatically

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

In my fragment class, I add a child view element programmatically to my layout conditionally :

```
LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,100);

container.addView(child, params);
```

Since the above code will be run conditionally, so, at some point, **I would like to check if the child view has added or not**, how to make this checking programmatically?

Comment: add a flag variable that says that the view were added.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you can simply use

```
findViewById(your_view_id)
```

method: If its result is null the view does not exists, otherwise the view is present

Comment: This is a very heavy computation cause it has to traverse the hierarchy of the views underneath the viewgroup, which can be a ton of views. the other answer .getParent() is a field lookup

Comment: are you saying that google engineers made the andorid sdk in a way that at the beginning of every activity every app does a very heavy computation one time for every view in a layout?? I don't think so

Comment: well, that's why the [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) patter exist when using ListView or RecyclerView, because we don't want to be going trough the hierarchy every single time, if the hierarchy hasn't change. And like i said, the time it takes is dependant on your depth of hierarchy. But, like always, you can go to the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3610) if you don't believe me.

Comment: Look, I'm not saying that findViewById is a lightweight operation, but actually the view holder pattern is used to prevent inflating the layout for every single row, which is by far a heavier operation. If you call findViewById just one time even the slower device you know will not suffer about it

Comment: Did you read the links i added into my comment? the first paragraph says this: **"Your code might call findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern."**

Answer (score 52):

If you creating view via inflater, you can check his parent

```
if(view.getParent() != null) {...}
```

Comment: perhaps   `public boolean hasParent(View view){
        return (view != null && view.getParent() != null);
    }`   Then he/she could call `if(hasParent(child)){...};` to check on it later.  (comment edited to deal with stupid formatting errors)

Answer (score 25):

Sorry for late reply but you may try this alternative:

use `container.getChildCount();` before adding and after adding a view. Like :

```
int x = container.getChildCount();

container.addView(child, params);

int y = container.getChildCount();

if(y > x)
   Toast.makeText(context, "View Successfully Added!", Toas.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 16):

Or if you have a **view** instance to find, you could:

```
if (container.indexOfChild(childView) == -1) {
  // Add child to container.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

With `AndroidX` you can use `ViewGroup.contains(view: View): Boolean` extension function.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot write a comment so I write it here as a solution:
From API level 19 you can call `isAttachedToWindow()` which doesn't help a lot, but if you are aiming `API 19` or higher, then this should work by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this

```
child.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            child.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // add to parent
        }
    });
```

or this one

```
child.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {

        }
    });
```