# Android how to check in FrameLayout already view add or not

Tags: android, android-framelayout

In my application i have use Framelayout and i add sticker view in FrameLayout.
before I add sticker view how to check in Framelayout already view added or not.

In my application show error as below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.
```

i have add StickerTextView in RecyclerView adapter itemView OnClickListener like below:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                tv_sticker.setText(""+ staticData.greetings);
                canvas.addView(tv_sticker);
           }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please add you code where you are adding your sticker view to frame layout?

Comment: You can check if the view element that will be the children has a parent using view.getParent().
Check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721991/check-if-view-element-is-added-to-layout-or-not-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve error using removeAllViews() method before addview like bellow:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            tv_sticker.setText(""+ staticData.greetings);
            canvas.removeAllViews();
            canvas.addView(tv_sticker);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this before you add the view:

```
if(stickerView.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ((ViewGroup)stickerView.getParent()).removeView(stickerView);
}
frameLayout.addView(stickerView);
```