# android - How to check if TextView is present in the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two different layouts, say `layout_1.xml` & `layout_2.xml`. Both layouts have same elements inside it, but `layout_2.xml` has an additional `TextView`.

Only one layout will be called according to my needs. I want to perform a check if the textView is available in the layout.

If the TextView is available, it should perform `textView.setText()`, else the other layout will be called.

Please refer the code below:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {
    SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);
    holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(singleItem.getUrl()).into(holder.itemImage);
    if (holder.lblDescription.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        holder.lblDescription.setText(singleItem.getDescription());
    }

}
```

The TextView `holder.lblDescription` is in `layout_2.xml`, but is not present in `layout_1.xml`.

Therefore, `layout_2.xml` is running with ease, but when it calls `layout_1.xml` its giving me this error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference.`

I know, the check I am performing is wrong. So, I need help in this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721991/check-if-view-element-is-added-to-layout-or-not-programmatically

Comment: @NileshRathod  I am not being able to understand how 'findViewById(your_view_id)' will help in finding the textView in layout.

Comment: If you have a small example for this, it might be helpfull for me. Thanks

Comment: If i am not wrong understanding your question, you mean check a View if it is visible in the screen? like for example you have a scrollview and a view will return false if he is not visible on the screen yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you are getting a null pointer exception because `lblDescription` isn't bound to anything in `layout_1.xml` where it isn't present. So basically what you can do is you can check

```
if(hold.lblDescription != null){
holder.lblDescription.setText(singleItem.getDescription());
}
```

instead of

```
 if (holder.lblDescription.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    holder.lblDescription.setText(singleItem.getDescription());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
     * check textview is present or not
     *
     * @param group : parent layout id
     */
    public boolean isTextViewPresent(ViewGroup group)
    {
        int count = group.getChildCount();
        View v;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            v = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof TextView)
            {
                return true;
            } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
                isTextViewPresent((ViewGroup) v);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The `isTextViewPresent((ViewGroup) v);` you call in your `else if` does nothing here because its return value is ignored, so this code won't work.

Comment: @Twometer, isTextViewPresent((ViewGroup) v); this is called to check textview in nested layouts as well

Comment: I know, but the result of this check is completely ignored. Change it to `if(isTextViewPresent((ViewGroup) v);) return true;`. With this code you no longer ignore the check, and you also do not break the for loop if there is first a ViewGroup that does not contain a TextView and then *after* that there is a ViewGroup containing one.

Comment: @Twometer You are completely wrong and provided code is fine. `isTextViewPresent((ViewGroup) v);` returns boolean and its not ignored